# AS-3 - How to create different draw styles?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, styles, prototype, draw

I know the `flash.display.Graphics` class is final and can't be extended nor its objects in sprites replaced. But I need to change its behavior or fake changed behavior. Normally in OOP I would extend a class, override its methods and call super methods like I want. But since that is not possible with `Graphics`, what is the best technique to achieve that ?

- **Is prototyping a way to modify the `Graphics` class the way I want ?**

---

Let's say I want to draw squares instead of circles:

```
public class Graphics2 extends Graphics
{
    override public function drawCircle(x: NUmber, y: Number, radius: Number): void
    {
        super.drawRect(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }
}
```

This is what I wished I could do. How can I fake it ? In the end I want to have objects that represent different draw styles. When I replace my `Graphics2` object I just change the complete style of drawing (circles turn to squares etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just map your own class to the methods you can't extend?

```
public class Graphics2 {
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    public static function drawCircle(obj:DisplayObject, x:Number, y:Number, r:Number):void  {
        obj.Graphics.drawRect(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }
}
```

A non-override-able Class will always remain that, and the classes that extend it will always use that final method, so any change would have to be mapped on to the actual functions (IMHO).

Comment: The import statement doesn't belong where you've put it.